# Masking a URL in a Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-masking

I'm trying to mask a page URL in a Wordpress installation. Let's say it's http://www.mysite.co.uk/wordpress/page and when this page is opened, I want the URL to show  http://www.mysite.co.uk/wordpress/anythingelse. The whole point of this is so that the URL cannot be shared, only accessed by authorised users, which means I also want it so that you cannot access this page by typing in /anythingelse. Is this possible and how do I go about this? I've got as far as .htaccess files but I have no experience working with this...

Answer (score 0):

If you use  http://www.mysite.co.uk/wordpress/anythingelse/ to actually show  http://www.mysite.co.uk/wordpress/page, then it means that you will be able to access http://www.mysite.co.uk/wordpress/page by reaching  http://www.mysite.co.uk/wordpress/anythingelse/... 
You might be trying to do this the wrong way. What is the point exactly? Do you know that in WordPress, you have two ways of protecting pages? One is to make it "Private" (just above the Publish or Update button) and the other one is to make it "Password protected" (same area). 
In any case, if you don't use a password but just play with the URLs, it will only be protected as long as the URL stays unknown. Anyone actually typing the right URL will, indeed, be able to access the page. 
You can also restrict access by IP. Try to be more explicit about why you want to protect this page.

Comment: I'm trying to set up pay-per-view content. I have an email delivery system but it only masks the link, not the URL after the link has been clicked

Comment: You can't protect your content this way. The browser is oblivious to the link masking you are using, it just says : this is the URL that is reached, I am showing the content. If you want to protect your content, there is only one way : make a check on the page, when the user accesses it. You can protect by password, force the user to log in before viewing, or, last possibilit, add a hash to your URL query parameters with an expiry key. I know no other solution for web protection

Comment: Hmmm.. A password is out of the question as it can easily be shared. What's the best way you know of to implement an expiry key?